# 32 byte empty buffer

Tags: php, encryption, buffer

I'm sure this is a simple thing to do but in php I need to make a 32 byte emptied out variable (i.e. it is all zeroes).  I am trying to decode in php an AES encrypted message where the initialization vector is all zeroes.  If I use null or 0 then I get an error that it needs to be 32 bytes and if I use "00000000000000000000000000000000" that is the string and is also not all zeroes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If by "all zero" you mean *zero bytes*:

```
str_repeat("\x0", 32)
```

Comment: Yes, I do mean all zero bytes.. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this:

```
pack(str_repeat('x', 32))
```